# Combine Reducer without Redux

Tags: reactjs, store, react-hooks, reducers, react-context

I have an application without redux, I handle the global state with hooks and the hook useReducer + context. I have 1 useReducer which makes like a Redux store. But to do this I can only send 1 reducer. In that reducer I have all the logic of the states, but I want to separate some functions of that reduce in other reducers. In redux there is the combineReducer to do this. But with hooks + context, how can I do this? How do I combine many reducers to send it to my Global Provider in the useReducer?

```
//Global Provider
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        isAuthenticated: null,
        user: {},
        catSelect: 10,
        productsCart,
        total
 });

//reducer with all cases
export default function(state , action ){

    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
           return etc...
        case SET_CATEGORIA:
           return etc...
        case 'addCart':
            return etc...
        case etc....
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

for now this works. But the reducer contains "cases" that do completely different things than other "cases". For example a "case" for authentication, another "case" to add products, another "case" to eliminate suppliers, etc.

With Redux I would have created more reducers (auth, shopCart, suppliers, etc) and use the combineReducer to control all that.

Without Redux I have to have everything mixed in 1 just reduce. So that I need, a combineReducer to combine many different reducers, or some other way of doing all this with Hooks + context

Answer (score 3):

I have been developing a bit of a boilerplate with this use case. this is how I am currently doing it.

Provider.js

```
import appReducer from "./reducers/app";
import OtherAppReducer from "./reducers/otherApp";

export const AppContext = createContext({});

const Provider = props => {
  const [appState, appDispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, {
    Thing: []
  });

const [otherAppState, otherAppDispatch] = useReducer(OtherAppReducer, {
    anotherThing: []
  });

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        state: {
          ...appState,
          ...otherAppState
        },
        dispatch: { appDispatch, otherAppDispatch }
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "action":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I started doing it that way. With multiple reducers, useReducer, dispatchs.
But the problem with this is when there are many states and dispatchs to send as value through the Provider.

<AppContext.Provider value={stateAuth,stateProducts,stateX,stateZ,dispatchAuth,dispatchProducts,dispatchEtc}/>
At some point there could be many values and it would not look very good

Comment: The way I see it, adding your state into a state key in the provider is the same as `export default combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2
})`. and the way I have it set up works well because you have your state separate from the dispatch, so you only need to concern yourself with one or the other. What is the issue with sending multiple values to the provider? You would have the same access with redux, no?