# React useReducer hook, how to handle multiple and unrelated types of actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-reducer

I'm using React hook `useReducer` to manage the state of a cart-like application. My `cartReducer` is used to handing adding/removing/changing quantity of items:

```
// utils/reducers.js
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS_TYPES.ADD_ITEM: {
      // ...
    }

    case ACTIONS_TYPES.REMOVE_ITEM: {
      // ...

    case ACTIONS_TYPES.EMPTY_CART: {
      // ...
    }

    case ACTIONS_TYPES.CHANGE_ITEM_QTY: {
      // ...
    }

    default: {
      throw new Error('Unrecognized action in cartReducer.');
    }
  }
};
```

Reducer `cartReducer` is used inside my cart component:

```
const [cart, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, { items: [] });
```

Now, I'd like to add notifications using my preferred library, but I don't know how to handle it. I think I have 3 options:

1. **Option 1**: pollute my reducer calling the library, i.e. adding functions like `showSuccessToast()` right before returning the new state;
2. **Option 2**: create new actions like `ACTIONS_TYPES.SHOW_SUCCESS_TOAST` but this requires me to change all `dispatch()` calls;
3. **Option 3**: create a new `cartNotificationReducer` adding functions like `showSuccessToast()`

I know that some of the option could be an anti-pattern, so I think that option 3 s the best. But `useReducer` accept only a single reducer... how can I combine them?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200785/react-usereducer-how-to-combine-multiple-reducers. In the redux world, the combinereducers approach is standard.

Comment: @DavidHall thanks for your comment, but I'm not using the redux library, so I can't use `combineReducer` function.

Comment: If you read down further in the answer linked above you will find discussion of non-redux solutions.