# What is a better approach to stack multiple actions in reducer per render (React, useReducer)?

Tags: reactjs, reducers, use-reducer

What is the best approach to using reduce logic from multiple actions per render? This example shows a basic example of my current solution (creating a new action that combines the logic), but there must be a better way.

**The basic example:**

I am using useReducer from React, not Redux

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {v1: 0, v2: 0});
```

Basic reducer that uses a new action that stacks the logic of the first two actions:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  const { type, payload: {v1, v2} } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SET_V1:
      return {...state, v1: setV1(v1)};
    case SET_V2:
      return {...state, v2: setV2(v2)};
    case SET_V1_AND_V2:
      return {...state, v1: setV1(v1), v2: setV2(v2)};
  }
}
```

Reduce logic delegated to functions to standardise logic:

```
const setV1 = (v1) => v1;
const setV2 = (v2) => v2;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you want to do this may I ask?

Comment: Because some of my actions share logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this could help:

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200785/react-usereducer-how-to-combine-multiple-reducers)
[Using Combine Reducer](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers#using-combinereducers)

```
const combineReducers = (slices) => (state, action) =>
  Object.keys(slices).reduce( // use for..in loop, if you prefer it
    (acc, prop) => ({
      ...acc,
      [prop]: slices[prop](acc[prop], action),
    }),
    state
  );
```